# What is the name of this type of rose?

Tags: identification, roses

I have recently bought a fragrant rose which hasn't bloomed yet. The stems are densely thorned. You can see its small and delicate thorns in the middle of the picture. Is there any chance anyone knows the name of this breeding?

[image: The foliage of an unknown rose breeding.]

Comment: Was it not named when you bought it? HOw do you know its fragrant can I ask? need to see flowers really to make any attempt at ID. Also not seeing any thorns at all on the leaves in the photo....

Comment: @Bamboo Thanks for your comment. I live in Iran and we name roses differently and very generally. To know about a type of breeding I have to know the English name of it. I know it is fragrant because I trust the seller and he told me so. I changed the picture. You can see the thorns in the middle of the picture. It has small and delicate thorns, but it has tons of them. I will upload a picture of its flowers as soon as it blooms.

Comment: I  can see the thorns now,  thanks,  but note, its not the English name I'm  after but the botanical name - yes, it might be expressed in English or a mix of that  and  Latin,but botanical  names are meant to be used worldwide ... but perhaps botanical names are not used where you live. Certainly add a pic of the flowers once they arrive...